# memory_map does not give expected results in Linux

Tags: osquery

The query `.all memory_map` on the Linux system gives unexpected results as start memory location = `0x00000000` as well as end memory location = `0x00000000` for all the attributes. Does it just seem weird?

**Operating System:** Kali Linux

**osquery version:** 4.0.2 (Current)

I've tried searching on the issues at [osquery/issues/](https://www.github.com/osquery/osquery/issues/)

The exact replication of the code on the CLI is:

```
osqueryi
.all memory_map
```

which gives the same result as:

```
osqueryi
SELECT * FROM memory_map
```

The output of `osqueryi` is nothing but a message showing that it is using a virtual database as follows.

`Using a virtual database. Need help, type '.help'`

And the output of `.all memory_map` is as follows:

```
+-------------------------------+------------+-------------+
| name                          | start      | end         |
+-------------------------------+------------+-------------+
| Reserved                      | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| System RAM                    | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| Reserved                      | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| PCI Bus 0000:00               | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| Video ROM                     | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| Adapter ROM                   | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| Reserved                      | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| System ROM                    | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| System RAM                    | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| ACPI Non-volatile Storage     | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| Reserved                      | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| System RAM                    | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| Reserved                      | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| System RAM                    | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| Reserved                      | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| ACPI Non-volatile Storage     | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| ACPI Tables                   | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| System RAM                    | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| Reserved                      | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| Graphics Stolen Memory        | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| PCI Bus 0000:00               | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| pnp 00:07                     | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| PCI Bus 0000:01               | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| 0000:01:00.0                  | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| 0000:01:00.0                  | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| 0000:00:02.0                  | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| PCI Bus 0000:01               | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| 0000:01:00.0                  | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| PCI Bus 0000:03               | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| 0000:03:00.0                  | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| iwlwifi                       | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| PCI Bus 0000:02               | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| 0000:02:00.1                  | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| 0000:02:00.1                  | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| r8169                         | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| 0000:02:00.0                  | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| rtsx_pci                      | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| 0000:02:00.0                  | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| 0000:00:1f.3                  | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| ICH HD audio                  | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| 0000:00:14.0                  | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| xhci-hcd                      | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| intel_xhci_usb_sw             | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| 0000:00:1f.3                  | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| ICH HD audio                  | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| 0000:00:1f.2                  | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| 0000:00:17.0                  | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| ahci                          | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| 0000:00:15.0                  | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| lpss_dev                      | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| i2c_designware.0              | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| lpss_priv                     | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| idma64.0                      | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| idma64.0                      | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| 0000:00:15.1                  | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| lpss_dev                      | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| i2c_designware.1              | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| lpss_priv                     | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| idma64.1                      | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| idma64.1                      | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| 0000:00:16.0                  | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| mei_me                        | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| 0000:00:17.0                  | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| ahci                          | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| 0000:00:1f.4                  | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| 0000:00:17.0                  | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| ahci                          | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| 0000:00:02.0                  | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| PCI MMCONFIG 0000 [bus 00-ff] | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| Reserved                      | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| pnp 00:07                     | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| Reserved                      | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| PCI Bus 0000:00               | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| pnp 00:00                     | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| INT344B:00                    | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| INT344B:00                    | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| pnp 00:00                     | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| INT344B:00                    | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| INT344B:00                    | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| INT344B:00                    | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| INT344B:00                    | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| pnp 00:00                     | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| iTCO_wdt                      | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| iTCO_wdt                      | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| pnp 00:00                     | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| pnp 00:00                     | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| pnp 00:00                     | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| pnp 00:00                     | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| Reserved                      | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| IOAPIC 0                      | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| Reserved                      | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| HPET 0                        | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| PNP0103:00                    | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| Reserved                      | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| pnp 00:07                     | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| pnp 00:07                     | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| pnp 00:07                     | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| pnp 00:07                     | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| MSFT0101:00                   | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| MSFT0101:00                   | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| Reserved                      | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| dmar0                         | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| dmar1                         | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| Local APIC                    | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| Reserved                      | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| pnp 00:07                     | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| INT0800:00                    | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| Reserved                      | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| System RAM                    | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| Kernel code                   | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| Kernel data                   | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| Kernel bss                    | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
| RAM buffer                    | 0x00000000 | 0x00000000  |
+-------------------------------+------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Yes, I was using the root user. I eventually changed my system to Kubuntu 19.04 and there it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

The `memory_map` table needs root permissions. Are you using root for the test?

(I can replicate that if I don't run with elevated permissions)